# [common clock framework]: what is the purpose of CLK_IS_BASIC flag?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, clock

all types of clocks use `CLK_IS_BASIC` flag at the time of registration with [common clock framework](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/clk.txt).

There is a small description in code related to this flag below:

```
#define CLK_IS_BASIC        BIT(5) /* Basic clk, can't do a to_clk_foo()
```

What is the purpose of this flag?

Comment: AFAICT, nothing except some TI OMAP code uses it, and it was introduced by somebody at TI. See commit f7d8caadfd2813cbada82ce9041b13c38e8e5282 for the description of the patch that introduced it.